# Spring Data MongoDB Configure Database bean

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

How to I configure the Mongo database bean? The bean is initialized by the MongoDB driver somehow with somethings pre-configured. I can't get the bean using `mongoClient.getDatabase()` because the database name either comes from the connection uri or just the standard property. And I can't define a new bean to update the old one like this `public MongoDatabase mongoDatabase(MongoDatabase database)` because that causes a ban definition cycle loop.  What do I do?

Not entirely relevant to the question, but here's my intention:

What I trying to do is add custom Conventions introduced in MongoDB Driver version 3.6.

http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/bson/pojos/

I know that spring data mongodb uses an older version, so I just replaced it with the newer one.

Comment: Are you excluding and Mongo Auto Configuration? If not you should do it if you want to declare Mongo bean yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take care of couple of things if you wish to configure MongoTemplate Or MongoDatabase yourself.

1. You need to disable spring boot's Mongo Auto Configuration.  You can achieve this as show below.

   ```
   @SpringBootApplication(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})
   ```
2. You have to create MongoTemplate or MongoDatabase bean and register it with Spring application context(using `@Bean`).

   ```
   @Bean
   public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {

      ServerAddress server = new ServerAddress(host,port);

      MongoClientOptions.Builder builder = MongoClientOptions.builder();
      CodecRegistry codecRegistry = CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(CodecRegistries.fromCodecs(new XYZCodec(..)),
      MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry());
      builder.codecRegistry(codecRegistry).build();
      MongoClientOptions options = builder.build();
      MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(server,options);

      return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient, mongoDataBase);
   }
   ```

Replace XYZCodec with the codec you want.

Comment: That's annoying... I'm creating a library that other people will use so it needs to support the different ways Mongo autoconfigured (so it's just easier to plug and play on existing projects). Thanks for the answer.